# Alternatives to grep/sed that treat new lines as just another character

Tags: sed, awk, grep

Both `grep` and `sed` handle input line-by-line and, as far as I know, getting either of them to handle multiple lines isn't very straightforward. What I'm looking for is an alternative or alternatives to these two programs that treat newlines as just another character. Is there any tool that fits such a criteria

Answer (score 8):

The tool you want is `awk`. It is record-oriented, not line-oriented, and you can specify your record-separator by setting the builtin variable RS. In particular, GNU awk lets you set RS to any regular expression, not just a single character.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example where `awk` uses one blank line to separate every record. If you show us what data you have, we can help you with it.

```
cat file
first line
second line
third line

fourth line
fifth line
sixth line

seventh line
eight line

more data
```

Running `awk` on this and reconstruct data using blank line as new record.

```
awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' file
first line second line third line
fourth line fifth line sixth line
seventh line eight line
more data
```

PS `RS` is not equal to file, is set to `RS=` blank, equal to `RS=""`

Comment: Never set variables in the awk argument list (where the list of files go) unless you have a very specific reason to (e.g. you need to change FS between files) and understand the consequences. In this case, try changing your script to use getline as `awk 'BEGIN{getline < "file"; print "<"$0">"}' RS= file` and `awk -v RS= 'BEGIN{getline < "file"; print "<"$0">"}' file` and note the difference. variables not populated in the BEGIN section are just one consequence, it also complicates processing multiple files. To set awk variables, use `-v var='value'` unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

1) Sed can handle a block lines together, not always line by line.

In sed, normally I use `:loop; $!{N; b loop};` to get all the lines available in pattern space delimited by newline.

Sample:

```
Productivity
        Google Search\
        Tips
        "Web Based Time Tracking,
        Web Based Todo list and
        Reduce Key Stores etc"
```

result (remove the content between ")

```
sed -e ':loop; $!{N; b loop}; s/\"[^\"]*\"//g' thegeekstuff.txt

Productivity
        Google Search\
        Tips
```

You should read this URL (Unix Sed Tutorial: 6 Examples for Sed Branching Operation), it will give you detail how it works.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/

2) For grep, check if your grep support -z option, which needn't handle input line by line.

```
  -z, --null-data
          Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero
          byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.   Like  the
          -Z  or --null option, this option can be used with commands like
          sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
```